# Are photons with different frequency distinguishable?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, photons, frequency, identical-particles

When i learn statistical mechanic, the teacher told me that photons with different frequency are distinguishable, i confused.
And the teacher say also photons with different polarization, direction are distinguishable, and the same as the phonon, and electrons in the lattice, i don't know if it is true.
And also, what is the difference if it is or not? how the experiment  can prove it is or not  distinguishable?

maybe distinguishable is not a good description, i want to identical is better.
In statistical mechanic, distinguishable means when the total partition function can factorized to product of single particle partition function q, we don't add 1/N! factor to the q^N

Comment: Just pass them through a prism and you'll see always the red photon going to one direction and the blue one going to the other

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Maybe an explanation of what it means for two photons to be indistinguishable would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider photons in a cubical box (a cavity) with side length $L$. The modes of the electromagnetic field are labeled by:

1. The integers $\{n_x, n_y, n_z\}$, which are related to the wavenumbers $k_x, k_y, k_z$ by
   \begin{equation}
   k_i = \frac{2\pi n_i}{L}, \ \ i=\{x, y, z\}
   \end{equation}
   and to the angular frequency $\omega$ (in units where $c=1$) by
   \begin{equation}
   \omega^2 = k_x^2 + k_y^2 + k_z^2 = \frac{4\pi^2}{L^2}\left(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_z^2\right)
   \end{equation}
2. The polarization (or *helicity*) $s=\pm1$.

A basis state of the electromagnetic field is a member of [Fock space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fock_space). In practice what this means is that for each combination of $\{n_x, n_y, n_z, s\}$, we say how many particles are in that state. An example state would be specified by:
\begin{eqnarray}
\{n_x, n_y, n_z, s\}&&\ \ \ \ \ \ \  {\rm Number\ of\ particles} \\
\hline 
\{1, 0, 0, +1\} && \ \ \ \ \ \  3 \\
\{1, 0, 0, -1\} && \ \ \ \ \ \  2 \\
\{0, 1, 0, +1\} && \ \ \ \ \ \  0 \\
\{0, 1, 0, -1\} && \ \ \ \ \ \ 13 \\
\vdots && \ \ \ \ \ \  \vdots \\
\{3, 14, 159, +1\} && \ \ \ \ \ \ 42 \\
\vdots && \ \ \ \ \ \  \vdots
\end{eqnarray}
In this example, the fact that photons are indistinguishable particles means that we cannot meaningfully add any additional labels the $3$ photons in the $\{1, 0, 0, 1\}$ state. Concretely, we can't name the photons Alice, Bob, and Charlene, and keep track of which photon is which.

However, we can distinguish the $3$ photons in the $\{1, 0, 0, 1\}$ state from the $2$ photons in the $\{1, 0, 0, -1\}$, since they have different quantum numbers. In this example, the $s$ quantum number is $+1$ in one case and $-1$ in the other case.

Comment: Thank you!
But still confused. Identical particles means exchange symmetry (boson) or anti-symmetry (fermion). In the fock space basis, second quantization basis, all photons are indistinguishable.
In statistical mechanic, if particles are indistinguishable, we need to add 1/N! to the q^N if total partition function can factorization.
Maybe here distinguishable or not is not how we detect it but how we describe it.
i don't exactly know what it the point, sorry.

Comment: @zjsun I think maybe what you are getting at is that if you write state as a tensor product of single particle states, then the state should be totally symmetric between all photons (regardless of the energy of each photon). This is true. The Fock space representation encodes this information differently; there are no wavefunctions for individual photons, but just the overall state of the system, and so the symmetrization requirement is built into the Fock space automatically.

Comment: In terms of counting in statistical mechanics, you would count each Fock space state (the list of occupation numbers) as a single state, for identical particles. For distinguishable particles, a single list of occuptation numbers could correspond to many states since permutations of the particles lead to different states.

Comment: @zjsun about the 1/N! , I think it would be informative for you to derive the partition function of non-interacting Bosons/ferminons from the grandcanonical density matrix, Exp[-beta (H-mu)]. To get the partition function, you need to do the trace of this density matrix. The different energy states doing the sandwiching will give raise to different partition functions containing bose and fermi statistics in their expressions. The appropriate 1/N! will arise naturally from the combinatory needed to keep track of the energy states.